# SPARQL multiple select with subquery

Tags: subquery, sparql

In SPARQL it is possibile to obtain something like this?

```
SELECT ?Name ?Input 
WHERE { ?s :Something ?Name . 
        ?s :Something ?Ui .
        { SELECT ?Ui ?Pn ?t 
          WHERE { 
          ?Ui :Something  ?Pn . 
          ?Ui :Something ?t } } }
```

where ?Input is an object that contains ?Ui ?Pn and ?t

Thanks
`

Comment: Hm, your query is actually valid SPARQL (well except missing blank prefix). Please edit this question to include some concrete example of sample data and the desired result

Comment: ?Input doesn't appear in the body of your query.  What do you mean by "?Input is an object that contains ?Ui ?Pn and ?t" ?

Comment: sorry, maybe I don't explained well my question....
I would know if it's possible to copy the values of ?Ui ?Pn ?t in a "new column" ?Input.

For example if the result of subquery is:
Ui = jhon. 
Pn=Jury
t=Larry
The value of Input is: jhon , Jury , Larry